# Unable to find SVG elements

Tags: svg, cypress

I have some of the elements under SVG.
I am trying to access them using CSS selector:
`cy.get('element selector').click()`, it says:

> unable to find the element using that selector.

But, with the same selector I am able to identify element in the browser using *chropath*.
Please help me.

Comment: please share your html markup

Comment: More specifically, share the svg-element that you are using in your html markup :)

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of ChroPath 6.0 supports the svg elements and svg child elements. Just inspect the svg elements or click on svg DOM node, ChroPath will generate the relative xpath for them.